# How to set environment variable for gulp-jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine, gulp

In my project I want the server to dynamically use a database based on an environment variable `DATABASE`. Depending on this variable I would load the files specific for that database from under a folder with the database name. (*mongodb -> server/mongodb/file.js*)

I set up an environment variable (`DATABASE="mongodb"`) for the node server using **noemon** so for example when I load a database file I use `require('./'+process.env.DATABASE+'/file')`.

Now my question is if I can configure gulp-jasmine with an environment variable?

Right now all my tests fail since the path resolves to ./undefined/file.

Comment: Does it work putting `DATABASE=name <executable>` before you executable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should either be able to launch your gulp task with the env variable set: `DATABASE=mongodb gulp jasmine` or set it within your gulp task `process.env.DATABASE = "mongodb"`.

Comment: If you use `DATABASE=mongodb gulp jasmine` to run the task, then in the Gulpfile you can access it with `process.env.DATABASE`